# How do I manually add a Tracking Protection List (TPL) to Internet Explorer that is not in the Internet Explorer gallery website?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, web-filtering

Currently, the only way I know to add a Tracking Protection List (TPL) to IE is by going to the [Internet Explorer gallery](http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/trackingprotectionlists), and then add it from that website.

But suppose I want to add this TPL  from this URL here: https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/adblock/ie/fanboy-ultimate-ie.tpl ([Fanboy Ultimate TPL](https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/adblock/ie/fanboy-ultimate-ie.tpl)), which is not in the IE gallery - How do I add this to Internet Explorer?

The TPL configuration UI does not seem to have an option to manually add a TPL from a URL:
[image]

I am using IE 9 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add every tracking list to IE with a small HTML file

1. Create a new text file and insert this code
   `<a href="javascript:window.external.msAddTrackingProtectionList('https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/adblock/ie/fanboy-ultimate-ie.tpl', 'Fanboy Adblock List')">Add TPL</a>`
2. Save it as *AddTPL.html* and open the HTML file with your Internet Explorer
3. Click on the *Add TPL* link and *Allow blocked content*
4. Click once more on the *Add TPL* link and add your TPL list

[image: Final result to prove everything is working]

Additional notes

- Change the URL to what ever tracking list you want to add.
  Here is for example the [Easylist TPL](http://easylist-msie.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.tpl)
- Fanboy's adblock list was merged with EasyList long ago. However, the Fanboy Tracking List, Enhanced Trackers List and Annoyances List (which are all included *in* the Ultimate list) are not included with the merge.  You can read more from Fanboy himself [here](http://forums.fanboy.co.nz/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16545).

Comment: Thanks for this. I know that [Fanboy's Adblock list was merged with EasyList](http://forums.fanboy.co.nz/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16545), however I believe this is not the case with the list I linked to: the Fanboy Ultimate list (which contains the [Fanboy Tracking List, Enhanced Trackers List and Annoyances List, along with the now-merged adblock list.](https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/filters.html))